# C#.Net Unspecified String to Color Converter

Tags: c#, wpf, colors

In this situation I have a list of customers that I would like to represent with colors.  How would I make a converter to generate a color based off the customer name, or portion of the name?

```
public class Customer
{
    public string CustomerName {get; set;}

    //other properties unrelated to the question....
}
```

Then in XAML somewhere I would like to be able to do the following:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomerName}"
           Foreground="{Binding CustomerName, 
           Converter={StaticResource MyStringToColorConverter}}"/>
```

I don't need the whole converter written out, just some ideas on how to convert an unspecified string to a color.

Comment: Could you post some code so we can understand what data structures you're working with?

Comment: far from clear, is this a fairly small number of customers? do they have to be same colour every time? etc. an example maybe of what you want.

Comment: Sorry this is a customer list of 100+.  I am alright if colors are not unique, but I would like a fair amount of variation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the binary values of the first 3 characters of their name and convert those to red, green, and blue values. The thing is though that regular names begin (assuming just upper case characters) with only 26 of the 256 possible binary values so you'll need to do some adding and multiplying to get in the 0-1 range. If you want more than 26 discrete values for each of red, green, and blue then consider aggregating the value for multiple letters.

Once you have a number in the 0-1 range, the next thing you want to do probably is normalize the values to avoid super dark or super bright colours. A possible way is to just use your standard normalization methods as follows.

```
intensity = sqrt(R*R + G*G + B*B)
if(intensity != 0)
{
    R = R / intensity;
    G = G / intensity;
    B = B / intensity;
}
```

This is something used quite frequently in computer graphics, basically you create a vector of length 1 in the same direction as the original vector. In this case we're treating a RGB value as a vector. Think of it like this, imagine the RGB colour space is a 3D plane, red is the X axis, green is the Y axis, and blue is the Z axis; this equation gives you any colour on the sphere with radius 1 (including pure red, pure green, pure blue, and all combinations in between.)

The last step would be multiplying each of rgb by 255 to get something in the range of [0,255).

This really is one of those problems you should mess around and experiment with yourself, it's usually quite interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Are the colors represented in hexadecimal (like for an HTML page) or System.Drawing brush colors? You could do something real simple like this:

```
    public class Customer
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Color
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.FirstName.StartsWith("fr", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    return "red";
                else if (this.FirstName.ToLower().Contains("jeff"))
                    return "green";
                else if (this.LastName.ToLower() == "smith")
                    return "blue";
                return "black";
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you'd use it like this:

```
        Customer ted = new Customer();
        ted.FirstName = "Ted";
        ted.LastName = "Smith";
        //this will give you "blue"
        var color = ted.Color;
```

I'd really need more information as to what you're app looks like, and what kind of color you need returned.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am wanting a larger amount of variation in the color scheme, with this method it would become quite tedious to brute force code the various desired colors.

Comment: @PrattHinds Okay, then please define how you would want to add colors based on the names. You can do it rather easily and dynamically, but it all depends on what the requirements are. Are you looking to get a unique color for each unique person? that would be easy to do.

Comment: the colors do not need to be unique necessarily, I would prefer the color be consistent for the customer as this will be used for font color settings to identify customers as well as graph and data grid colors.

Answer (score 0):

To define a color you need 3 numbers between 0 and 255 (red, green, and blue). You could do something as simple as using the ASCII values of the first three letters of the name to generate a color.